# Cannot Get Sound Over HDMI in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi, sound-card

Windows 7 has been really good to me, I never needed to install any drivers & that included sound. Win7 took care of all that, but because of that I don't have any extra controls. Just the native Windows sound controls. I connected my LCD and PC using the HDMI, works great with video but the sound seems to stick with the PC speakers.

My friend somehow solved this in Vista, but to port the sound to the LCD, he always had to restart the computer, which I found really weird and never made me interested to even know how he did that. There has to be way to do this easily.

Please let me know if anyone else had the same problem & solved it somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem with my USB headset all the time.

Right click the sound icon in your taskbar and select "Playback devices".  Find your HDMI audio in the list and set it as the default.

I constantly have to do this every time I try to use my headset - I hope you don't have the same issue with your monitor speakers!