# Cannot get HDMI audio output to work

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi

I've searched Google for the solution as this seems to be common issue and resolution seems to be simple as described in this answer:

> [Cannot Get Sound Over HDMI in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/125278/cannot-get-sound-over-hdmi-in-windows-7)

However I don't have the HDMI output in my system sounds device list as can be seen from a screenshot:

[image]

My picture works just fine on the LCD TV but sound still plays on my laptop. How do I fix this to get the audio to play on my TV as well?

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-sound/windows-7-cant-get-hdmi-audio-the-hdmi-device-does/a494af37-9780-4b4a-895c-b2c1fce17fe6) help?

> The issue here can be one of several issues, the following may apply:
>
> - The HDMI graphics card may support HDMI Video, but may not support HDMI Audio
> - You may need to set the HDMI audio device as the default sound device
> - You may need to update your HDMI video card drivers for your version of Windows
> - If your HDMI video card does not support audio, you may need to connect additional audio cables between the PC and TV